# Hover mouseout to list or not

Tags: jquery

I tried to make hover on `.logo` then `.nav_b` be slideDown/slideUp, and if mouse continue move to `.nav_b` then it will still visible.

These code works fine but when mouse move from .logo to `.nav_b` it will fire the statement `.logo mouseout` .
 How to set a flag or.. to invoke mouse `moveout` from `.logo` to `.nav_b` or not?   any suggestion? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/6URAb/

```
$('.logo').hover(function(){
    $('.nav_b').stop(true, true).slideDown({duration: 200, queue: false});
},function(){
    $('.nav_b').stop(true, true).slideUp({duration: 200, queue: false});
});

$('.nav_b').hover(function(){
    $('.nav_b').stop(true, true).show();
},function(){
    $('.nav_b').stop(true, true).slideUp({duration: 200, queue: false});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to **change your Markup** and attaching the hover event to the `.head` element
**Javascript**

```
$(function () {

    $('.head').hover(function () {
        $('.nav_b').stop(true, true).slideDown({
            duration: 200,
            queue: false
        });
    }, function () {
        $('.nav_b').stop(true, true).slideUp({
            duration: 200,
            queue: false
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="head">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
    <div class="nav_b">
        <div class="search">search</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/6URAb/1/)**

**EDIT**

With the same marup if you want to achieve it , then you would be needing to use a combination of **setTimeout** and **cleartimeout**. Something like this

```
$(function () {
    var TIME_OUT;
    $('.logo').hover(function () {
        if (TIME_OUT) clearTimeout(TIME_OUT);
        $('.nav_b').stop(true, true).slideDown({
            duration: 200,
            queue: false
        });
    }, function () {
        $('.nav_b').stop(true, true).slideUp({
            duration: 200,
            queue: false
        });
    });

    $('.nav_b').hover(function () {
        $('.nav_b').stop(true, true).show();
    }, function () {
        TIME_OUT = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.nav_b').stop(true, true).slideUp({
                duration: 200,
                queue: false
            });
        }, 250);
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/6URAb/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for reply, but if not change html makeup is it possible?